# Thank you to our 9 inaugural "enthusiastic users"!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, badges, participation

Thank you so much, to all of you that have been [enthusiastic](https://materials.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast) about helping create this site, and helping it grow during its first 30 days of life:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hopefully there will be many, many more years and decades to come!

Thank you also to Henry and TheSimpliFire for being [enthusiastic about our Meta site](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast):

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Let's continue this trend! If it's not too hard for you, please try to drop by our site and meta site once a day!**

Comment: As of today, we have reached 18.

Comment: @Tyberius it's so great to see so many people so enthusiastic about building this community! 18 alone is not enough to build something that lasts several decades without falling apart though. Many people could be active while they're students but move on to other things if they don't land a tenured position in the field. I would feel more comfortable if the group of highly active members was much bigger!